# calculating sum based upon date range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

my DataFrame is look like this

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-01-01 07:14:00','2007-01-01 07:25:00','2007-01-01 08:00:00', '2007-01-01 09:14:00','2007-01-01 09:33:12'],'sent':[0.32,0.34,0.45,0.7,0.22]})
```

Now, I want to add new column `sum` based upon hourly date range, for example, `2007-01-01 07:00:00` To `2007-01-01 08:00:00` column `sum` = `0.32+0.34= 0.66`. for next hour `2007-01-01 08:00:00` To `2007-01-01 09:00:00` column `sum= 0.45` and for 3rd hour `2007-01-01 09:00:00` To `2007-01-01 10:00:00` column `sum= 0.7+0.22= 0.92` Thanks in advance.
**My desired output is like:**

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-01-01 07:14:00','2007-01-01 07:25:00','2007-01-01 08:00:00','2007-01-01 09:14:00','2007-01-01 09:33:12'],'sent':0.32,0.34,0.45,0.7,0.22],'sum':['na',0.66,0.45,'na',0.92],'Datehour':['nan','2007-01-01 08:00:00','2007-01-01 09:00:00','nan','2007-01-01 10:00:00']})
```

Comment: Your expected output does not match your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.Grouper` and group on 1H intervals:

```
# If necessary, convert to datetime.
# df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1H')).sent.sum().reset_index()

                 Date  sent
0 2007-01-01 07:00:00  0.66
1 2007-01-01 08:00:00  0.45
2 2007-01-01 09:00:00  0.92
```

---

Another option is resampling:

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('1H').sum().reset_index()

                 Date  sent
0 2007-01-01 07:00:00  0.66
1 2007-01-01 08:00:00  0.45
2 2007-01-01 09:00:00  0.92
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ coldspeed

Comment: @Faisal hi if this is what you need,  would you consider accept it ? check mark at the left

Comment: yes I guess it helped me a lot but a minor thing I want closing hour time for example instead of  `2007-01-01 07:00:00` I need `2007-01-01 08:00:00` Thanks

Comment: @Faisal check shift: df = df.set_index('date').shift(-1, freq='1H').reset_index()

Comment: hi @coldspeed thanks a lot. One more :)  thing I have observed new dataframe give me only two columns are rest of df columns lost. I want to preserve other columns as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Faisal I understand you have a problem to solve, but please refrain from making users iteratively debug/solve your problems. If you have any follow ups, the courteous thing to do would be to accept the answer now as it solved the problem (as originally stated) and open a follow up question. Again, it will mean more work for you, but we are unpaid volunteers as well, so please respect our time :-)

Comment: oops, I am sorry, I am really new to this interface. I did know I had to accept the answer, however, I tried by clicking up arrow but it was saying you need some level to do so.. Sorry again. Now I found it and I have checked it. Thanks